# Convert nested JSON from a CSV into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am desperately trying to convert a nested JSON feature within a CSV into data frame rows. Could you help?

**Sample CSV row**

> 2021-09-26T08:25:43.021051958Z,"{""level"":""info"",""message"":""Success
> (Cached)"",""request"":""GET /api/v1/settingsid=3"",""httpCode"":200,""service"":""stats-vis-backend"",""timestamp"":""2021-09-26
> 08:25:43""}",ip-10-xxx-xxx-18.eu-central-1.compute.internal,podname-75ffdf6b-gns8v

**Desired output (using JSON part only):**

| id | message | request | httpCode | service | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Success (Cached) | GET /api/v1/settings?id=3 | 200 | stats-vis-backend | 2021-09-26 08:25:43 |

If this would be the data frame output structure, I would be more than happy. I tried JSON normalize etc., but I am far away from a solution.

Thanks so much!!

Best
David

Full Code trial (based on SeaBean):

```
import csv
import ast
import pandas as pd

# read CSV 
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/David/xaa.csv',sep=',', header=None)

print(df.head(1))

# convert string of JSON/dict to real JSON/dict 
# the JSON/dict is at column `1` (second column from left)
df[1] = df[1].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Create dataframe from the JSON part
df_json = pd.DataFrame(df[1].tolist())

print(df_json.head(1))
```

Full output dump

```
File "/Users/David/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-7-86e494aa8f0c>", line 12, in <module>
    df[1] = df[1].apply(ast.literal_eval)

  File "/Users/David/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 4138, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)

  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer

  File "/Users/David/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 59, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')

  File "/Users/David/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    > next start
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Sample Output df1**

```
0         {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
1         {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
2         {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
3         {"level":"info","message":"Success","request":...
4         {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
                                ...                        
249995    {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
249996    {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
249997    {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
249998    {"level":"info","message":"Success","request":...
249999    {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","...
Name: 1, Length: 250000, dtype: object
```

**Sample toDict() Output of df1**

```
{0: '{"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","request":"GET /api/v1/settings?id=3","httpCode":200,"service":"stats-vis-backend","timestamp":"2021-09-26 08:25:43"}',
 1: '{"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)","request":"GET /api/v1/settings?id=3","httpCode":200,"service":"stats-vis-backend","timestamp":"2021-09-26 08:26:17"}',
```

**Output print(df.iloc[[4480]])**

```
                               0             1  \
4480  2021-09-26T12:00:58.983344643Z  > next start   

                                                   2  \
4480  ip-10-xxx-xxxx-30.eu-central-1.compute.internal   

                                  3  
4480  xxxx-converter-75ffxf6b-jq2w7
```

Comment: What did you try? share the code please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) on the list of column values of the second column (with JSON) after converting the string of JSON to real JSON (not in string), as follows:

```
# read CSV 
df = pd.read_csv(r'mycsv.csv', sep=',', header=None)

# convert string of JSON/dict to real JSON/dict 
import ast
# the JSON/dict is at column `1` (second column from left)
df[1] = df[1].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# Create dataframe from the JSON part
df_json = pd.DataFrame(df[1].tolist())
```

If you have already read the CSV into dataframe with column header, you can also use the column label of the second column instead of `1` for the column label for second column in the codes above.

**Result:**

```
print(df_json)


  level           message                   request  httpCode            service            timestamp
0  info  Success (Cached)  GET /api/v1/settingsid=3       200  stats-vis-backend  2021-09-26 08:25:43
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I adapted your code.  first output is                                 0  \
0  2021-09-26Txxx
                                                   1  \
0  {"level":"info","message":"Success (Cached)",xxxx  
                                                2  \
0  ip-10-xxx-xxx-18.eu-central-1.comxxx
                               3  
0  xxx-converter-xxxxx    which is great. But then it says   File "python3.8/ast.py", line 47, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,

  File "<unknown>", line 1
    > next start
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I edited my original post with the currently used code to clarify things. PS: my csv  has no label, so I had hoped it would work the way you sketched it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @David, so you got SyntaxError error at the step with `ast` ?  Can you post the whole trace dump at the end of your question ?   I run the same code without problem.  So, need to check your dump to check for more info

Comment: Hi @SeaBean, for sure, I just updated the post and inserted the full dump. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @David  The dump just further confirm the problem occurred during `ast` parsing the string of JSON.  Can you try replacing `.apply()` with `.map()` ?  i.e.  `df[1] = df[1].map(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: @David  Also, can use see the JSON by printing the 2nd column by  `print(df[1])` ?

Comment: Hi SeaBan, thank you so much again! I added the print(df1) output in the post - which looks fine for me. The apply->map change unfortunately has not been successful on the first run. Still error  File "<unknown>", line 1
    > next start
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @David The problem seems lying on the step converting the string of dict to dict by `ast.literal_eval`   Common reason is there exist some invalid text/format in the dict.  Would you please dump the first few lines of `df[1]` for investigation ?   You can dump by `df[1].head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: @David  You can also have a quick check whether `eval` instead of `ast.literal_eval` can parse the dict.  However, see whether the data in your dict is trusted data free from possible malicious codes inside.  If not trusted data, don't use `eval`  That is, check with `df[1] = df[1].apply(eval)`

Comment: I inserted the output for df[1].head(10).to_dict() as asked for In the post. Eval instead of literal_eval doesn't seem to already solve the problem, though, as prompts yet another error. But I feel we are so close!! File "<string>", line 1
    > next start
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @David  I used your dump of first 2 rows and found no error running `df[1].apply(ast.literal_eval)`.   One possibility is some data down the rows (not in the first 2 rows) consists of error syntax.  Can you try to run only on the first 2 rows by `df[1].head(2).apply(ast.literal_eval)` and see whether it works ?

Comment: SeaBean, I think you have been very right with your analysis. The first 4480 rows can be parsed without errors. I therefore had a look on the very next row and learned that df(1) does not consist of a valid JSON, but " > next start". I presume this resulted due to a parallelized data export. :-/ Is there any way to skip invalid entries? The CSV is >10GB. Or maybe I should try to remove any invalid row before further data work?

Comment: @David  Hhmm, I think you have to clean up invalid JSON first.  You can either drop the row if you can.  If not, replace the entry at that row by something e.g. an empty dict.  If this kind of error data should be rare (I think so, otherwise, you should have already noticed of this), this approach should be the easiest to do other than devise complicated solution to fix the data.

Comment: @David  Wish you get good progress at cleaning up the data.  As the problem is related to data and not my solution, remember to accept my solution and upvote it too.   I will continue to answer to your further question as far as possible.  No worry!